# Do i need to ignore .cache folder in GIT

Tags: javascript, git, visual-studio, version-control, azure-devops

What is the use of GIT .cache folder and do i need to ignore it in .gitignore file? 
As it is creating hundreds of untracked files.
is .cache locally relevant or should i commit it to git?

Comment: Git does not use anything named `.cache`. Other things might; such files might or might not be build artifacts that should not be committed; that depends on those other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As torek mentioned, Git doesn't create a folder named `.cache`.  This folder is created by some other tool, which in this case is probably Visual Studio.

However, in general, caches are discardable and exist solely for performance; they can be rebuilt from other data.  Since you should not check in any build artifacts or temporary data to your repository, it's probably best to ignore the `.cache` folder (and if you have any, the `bin` and `obj` folders as well).

Comment: Thanks @torek and bb2204. I realized the cache was created by parcel bundler. I added it to .gitignore

Comment: How to include all the .cache folder or files in gitgnore

Comment: You'd add a line that says, `.cache` to `.gitignore`.